# My Code isn't compiling, can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: c++

So far this is what I have come up with for my program but I can't figure out why it wont compile correctly, I'm getting a lot of errors. Anyone have any suggestions? The program needs to merge male and female clients from two different files and output to another file. Thanks!

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

     ifstream inFile1;
     ifstream inFile2;
     ofstream outFile1;
     int mClientNumber, fClientNumber;
     string mClientName, fClientName;
     bool atLeastOneFileNotAtEnd = true;
     bool inFile1Written = false;
     bool inFile2Written = false;
 cout << "File merge processing starting" ;
 inFile1.open("MaleClients.rtf");
 inFile2.open("FemaleClients.rtf");
 outFile1.open("MergedClients.rtf");
 inFile1 >> mClientNumber;
 inFile1 >> mClientName;
 inFile2 >> fClientNumber;
 inFile2 >> fClientName;
 while ( atLeastOneFileNotAtEnd == true )
 {
   if (inFile1 == EOF)
   {
     if (inFile2Written == false)
     {
       outFile1 << fClientNumber << endl;
       outFile1 << fClientName << endl;
       inFile2Written = true;
     }
   else if (inFile2 == EOF)
     if (inFile1Written == false);
     {
       outFile1 << mClientNumber << endl;
       outFile1 << mClientName << endl;
       inFile1Written = true;
     }
   else if (mClientNumber < fClientNumber)
     outFile1 << mClientNumber << endl;
     outFile1 << mClientName << endl;
     inFile1Written = true;
   else
     outFile1 << fClientNumber << endl;
     outFile1 << fClientName << endl;
     inFile2Written = true;
   }


   if ((inFile1 ! EOF) && (inFile1Written == true))
   {
     inFile1 >> mClientNumber;
     inFile1 >> mClientName;
     inFile1Written = false;
   }
   if ((inFile2 ! EOF) && (inFile2Written == true))
   {

     inFile2 >> fClientNumber;
     inFile2 >> fClientName;
     inFile2Written = false;
   }
   if ((inFile == EOF) && (inFile2 == EOF))
   {
     atLeastOneFileNotAtEnd = false;
   }
 }
 inFile1.close();
 inFile2.close();
 outFile1.close();
 cout << "Merging Complete"

  system("pause");
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: post the errors which you get.

Comment: This is my first error and I'm confused because I'm not really sure what it means, 84 23 [Error] no match for 'operator==' in 'inFile1 == -1'

Comment: `if (inFile1 == EOF)` what are trying to check here? If the file is opened successfully? or if you ave reached the end of the file stream?

Comment: If reached the end of the file stream

Comment: You need to include the error output from your compiler in your post so that people can tell, for example, which line the error is on. You should also state which IDE/compiler you are using.

Comment: You need to test eof() **after** you tried to read a variable; it will not be detected before the first read failed. In that case, your code would go on with uninitialized values. The canonical way to check is to test the return value of the operator>>(), like "if(! (inFile2 >> fClientNumber) ) { clean_up() && go_home_() } else { do_something(); }

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is your way to check end-of-file.

```
if (inFile1 == EOF)
```

should be

```
if (inFile1.eof())
```

And somewhere you are using `inFile` which is not defined before, it should be `inFile1`.

Another problem is, it seems you have put an unnecessary `;` here

```
if (inFile1Written == false);
                            ^
```

Comment: Oh ok! thank you, I was very confused on how to check end of file. I'll look over it and see where I am after.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `EOF` macro from C. There is no need to do this. Stick with C++ and use `ifstream.eof()`, and get rid of the `cstdlib` include.